# twilio_view decorator always gives 403 in production

Tags: python, django, twilio

I'm using django-twilio to try and respond to text messages coming from Twilio account. As it recommends using the twilio_View decorator to imrove upon @csrf_exempt, I'm using it. Problem is, it doesnt work. No matter what I try, I always get 403.
Things I've done:

1. Twilio test account. Added TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN in settings, which match the test account values.
2. Double checked the url set in twilio exists, and not HTTPS. Set in the properties of the twilio SMS phone number settings.
3. Upgraded to South 1.0, run migrations.
4. Turn off DJANGO_TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION, and it works.
5. Number the text is coming from is verified in twilio.
6. Production settings, so debug=False

Running Django 1.4.20, Twilio 4.5, django-twilio 0.8, python 2.7.

View is stupid simple:

```
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view
from twilio.twiml import Response

@twilio_view
def say_hello(request):
    r = Response()
    r.message('hello there')
    return r
```

If you replace the twilio decorator with the @csrf_exempt decorator, it all works fine. I get the response back to my phone.

In the decorator it looks for the HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE value in the request. Looking in my twilio alerts I can't see that value in the request. Don't know if it will show up there or not?

Comment: Are you using Twilio subaccounts at all?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio team member here.

Are you importing twiml? Try making the first line of your say-hello function:

```
r = twiml.Response()
```

Comment: yes - all imports are correct. Updated question to show.

Comment: Okay, let me try to get it running on my end.

Comment: do you need https for this to work, as @VinodKurup suggested? None of the twilio documents say you do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you are doing, so I would suggest removing the `@twilio_view` decorator and logging the X-Twilio-Signature header in your view to see what it is and manually checking to see if it's correct. (Basically, redoing the logic of the `@twilio_view` decorator in your view, just to see what's going on).

This [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/security#validating-requests) kinda suggests that you should use a SSL URL before Twilio will add the X-Twilio-Signature to its request, but I'm not really sure if that's true.

Comment: Good link - I'll take a look. Debugging this is awful - one character wrong and it returns false. Great.